# Laravel Sail with Laravel Nova: ...vendor/laravel/nova/src/NovaCoreServiceProvider.php not found

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-nova, laravel-sail

I recently tried to deploy my **laravel Nova** project in docker, and my search brought me to **laravel sail**.

So having the default *docker-compose.yml* file included in the project, I ran the **'sail up'** command in my project working directory

`./vendor/bin/sail up`

This command downloaded and setup the images specified in the *docker-compose.yml* file

```
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - meilisearch
            - selenium
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    meilisearch:
        image: 'getmeili/meilisearch:latest'
        platform: linux/x86_64
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MEILISEARCH_PORT:-7700}:7700'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmeilisearch:/data.ms'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "wget", "--no-verbose", "--spider",  "http://localhost:7700/health"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
    selenium:
        image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
        volumes:
            - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
```

Then created and launched docker containers from the images

```
Creating network "my-project_sail" with driver "bridge"
Creating my-project_meilisearch_1 ... done
Creating my-project_redis_1       ... done
Creating my-project_selenium_1    ... done
Creating my-project_mailhog_1     ... done
Creating my-project_mysql_1       ... done
Creating my-project_laravel.test_1 ... done
```

All the containers were executed successfully except for the *my-project_laravel.test_1* container which looped continuously displaying the following error

```
laravel.test_1  | 2022-01-01 09:54:41,943 INFO success: php entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
laravel.test_1  | 
laravel.test_1  | In ClassLoader.php line 571:
laravel.test_1  |
laravel.test_1  |   include(/var/www/html/vendor/composer/../laravel/nova/src/NovaCoreServicePr
laravel.test_1  |   ovider.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
laravel.test_1  |
laravel.test_1  |
laravel.test_1  | 2022-01-01 09:54:45,682 INFO exited: php (exit status 1; not expected)
laravel.test_1  | 2022-01-01 09:54:46,691 INFO spawned: 'php' with pid 26
laravel.test_1  | 2022-01-01 09:54:47,693 INFO success: php entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
laravel.test_1  | 
laravel.test_1  | In ClassLoader.php line 571:
laravel.test_1  |
laravel.test_1  |   include(/var/www/html/vendor/composer/../laravel/nova/src/NovaCoreServicePr
laravel.test_1  |   ovider.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
laravel.test_1  |
laravel.test_1  |
laravel.test_1  | 2022-01-01 09:54:51,307 INFO exited: php (exit status 1; not expected)
laravel.test_1  | 2022-01-01 09:54:52,322 INFO spawned: 'php' with pid 33
```

**What I've tried so far**

I executed the below command to actually display the content of the *'/var/www/html/vendor/laravel'* directory within the container

```
$ docker exec my-project_laravel.test_1 ls /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/
framework
nova
sail
sanctum
serializable-closure
tinker
ui
```

But listing the contents of the nova directory displayed above yields *"No such file or directory"*

```
$ docker exec my-project_laravel.test_1 ls /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/nova/
ls: cannot access '/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/nova/': No such file or directory
```

After inspecting the *vendor/laravel* directory in the project on the host machine (Windows 11), I discovered the *nova* directory's icon indicates that it's a shortcut but when I open its properties, I don't see the shortcut tab. And the folder has content

[This is the content of the vendor/laravel directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nl0HD.png)

Any help from this point would be great

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#installing-composer-dependencies-for-existing-projects) I found this command:

```
docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v $(pwd):/var/www/html \
    -w /var/www/html \
    laravelsail/php81-composer:latest \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Replace the php version number with yours than run this command in wsl.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you ran composer install from your host computer (Windows 11), however to make it work properly you want to do this from within docker, as it will create a symlink linux style (with the command `ln`).

**So you might want to remove your `vendor` folder first that was created by composer. After this you can enter your container by running `docker-compose exec laravel.test bash` and you will be in your container as if you ssh'd into it.**

*Some background as why this command does this: laravel.test is your container name given it the [docker-compose definition](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/stubs/docker-compose.stub#L4). Bash is a shell which is available in the [current linux distro used by the Dockerfile](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/runtimes/8.1/Dockerfile#L1).*